Horizontal Stack effect while scrolling vertically with css, js
I have been trying to acheive this effect but, have failed to do so.
Effect: https://imgur.com/a/dBvwa3e
Can anyone help me out? This is as much as I have been able to achieve:
Tried Approach:
I have tried to attach each image change to the scroll position within the parent container but, doing so with react means no animation or transitions are applying. Or I just do not know how to do it properly.


function Section() {
  const colors = [
    <div className={styles.card}>
      <img src={img1} alt="" />
    </div>,
    <div className={styles.card}>
      <img src={img2} alt="" />
    </div>,
    <div className={styles.card}>
      <img src={img3} alt="" />
    </div>,
    <div className={styles.card}>
      <img src={img4} alt="" />
    </div>,
  ];
  const headings = [
    "X",
    "Y",
    "Z",
    "W",
  ];

  const contents = [
    "X",
    "Y",
    "Z",
    "W",
  ];
  const [scrolling, setScrolling] = useState(colors[0]);
  const [heading, setHeading] = useState(headings[0]);
  const [content, setContent] = useState(contents[0]);
  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (!containerRef.current) return;

    const scrollTop = containerRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    console.log(scrollTop);
    if (scrollTop >= -500 && scrollTop < 0) {
      setScrolling(colors[0]);
      setHeading(headings[0]);
      setContent(contents[0]);
    } else if (scrollTop >= -1000 && scrollTop < -500) {
      setScrolling(colors[1]);
      setHeading(headings[1]);
      setContent(contents[1]);
    } else if (scrollTop >= -1500 && scrollTop < -1000) {
      setScrolling(colors[2]);
      setHeading(headings[2]);
      setContent(contents[2]);
    } else if (scrollTop >= -2000 && scrollTop < -1500) {
      setScrolling(colors[3]);
      setHeading(headings[3]);
      setContent(contents[3]);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const parentElement = containerRef.current;

    parentElement.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      parentElement.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.cardContainer} ref={containerRef}>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <section className={styles.cardParent}>
          {scrolling}
          {window.innerWidth > 1100 && (
            <React.Fragment>
              <div className={`${styles.card} ${styles.dummy1}`}>
                <img src={bg} alt="" />
              </div>
              <div className={`${styles.card} ${styles.dummy2}`}>
                <img src={bg} alt="" />
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </section>

        <aside className={styles.sideHeadings}>
          <section className={styles.sideHeadingsContent}>
            <h3>{heading}</h3>
            <p>{content}</p>
            <Link to={"/signup"} className="btn">
              Let's Start
            </Link>
          </section>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
.cardContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; 
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  height: 2300px;
  width: 90vw;
  overflow: visible;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 3rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10vh;

  height: 70vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.cardParent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  
}

.card > img {
  margin-right: auto;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100% ;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.dummy1{
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -9;
  display: flex;
}

.dummy1 > img{
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  translate: 15% 5% 0;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 3rem !important;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(149,149,149);
}

.dummy2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -90;
  display: flex;  
}
.dummy2 > img{
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  translate: 33% 12% 0;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 2rem !important;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(149,149,149);
}

.sideHeadings {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sideHeadingsContent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;

  height:60%;
  width:100%;
}

.sideHeadingsContent > h3 {
  font-size: var(--h2-large);
  font-family: var(--font-inter);
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgb(201,201,201);
}

.sideHeadingsContent >p{
  font-family: var(--font-poppins);
  color: rgb(149,149,149);
  font-size: var(--para-large);
}

.sideHeadingsContent > a{
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(221,255,0,.5)60%,rgb(221,255,0) 100%);
  /* transition: all .6s ease !important; */
}
.sideHeadingsContent > a:hover{
  background: black !important;
}

/* Tablet */

@media  (width<= 1100px) {
  .cardContainer{
    margin-bottom: 30vh;
  }
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .sideHeadings{
    width: 90vw;
  }

  .sideHeadingsContent{
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    gap: 2rem;
    width: 90vw;
  }
  .sideHeadingsContent > h3{
    font-size: var(--h3-large);
  }

  .wrapper img{
    width: 90vw;
    height: 40vh;
  }

  .sideHeadingsContent > a{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media (width<=768px) {
  .sideHeadingsContent > h1{
    font-size: var(--h1-heading-mobile);
  }

  .sideHeadingsContent > h3{
    font-size: var(--h3-heading-mobile);
  }

  .wrapper img{
    width: 90vw;
    height: 40vh;
  }
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



I just can't figure out this animation or transition, or whatever it is. The design is at https://proximab.framer.website/
